# Current Sensing with Op-Amp, do I need a shunt resistor in series with the load on the output?

Tags: operational-amplifier, bjt, current-sensing, negative-feedback

Hi I am building a circuit to measure current draw from a load, I opted for a voltage follower with a transistor and a shunt in between, The transistor is needed to allow higher currents to flow through the load, here is my schematic:

[image]

The Op-Amp is configured with Negative Feedback, So as long as the Input Voltage plus the shunt voltage plus the transistor Vce is lower than the Collector Voltage, the transistor would be in saturation mode (I'm actually not sure).

If the BJT is in saturation mode, the voltage across the load would be exactly the same as the Input Voltage, also the current across the shunt is the same as the current across the load, allowing to sense the current with a differential amplifier across the shunt.

What I am not really sure is if I need to place a resistor between the Op-Amp Output and the base of the BJT, I think that the Op-Amp would compensate by itself, but idk.

So the actual question is if a resistor needed between the base of the BJT and the Op-Amp output.

**EDIT:**

This is the second stage for a DC Variable Voltage source.

This stage has three purposes:

> -The first, to keep the voltage across the load equal to the input voltage.
>
> -The second is to be able to measure the load current with a differential amplifier across the load
>
> -The third to increase me maximum current that can be supplied to the load. Since the first stage is 1.5 Amps max, I would like to make this at least 3 Amp max

Comment: If your aim is only to be able to sense current through the 1k load resistor using the 100m shunt, it's not clear what the purpose of the opamp and transistor are. Are they already part of an existing circuit?

Comment: @brhans I think the circuit shown is intended to be a variable voltage supply where an omitted differential amp circuit is to measure the current through the load via the Shunt voltage.

Comment: You don't need to, but the resistor does make it so the opamp doesn't have to be so squirrely to maintain equilibrium (takes only a small change in output voltage for a large change output current). Things will get more squirrely as your load resistance is reduced (or if it is something other than a resistance) since it helps out in reducing this sensitivity.

Comment: This is the second stage for a DC Variable Voltage source, that I would like to make 5A max, so something like a TIP41 can be used.

This stage has two purposes, the first, to keep the voltage across the load equal to the input voltage, and the second is to be able to measure the load current with a differential amplifier across the load.

Comment: I responded to the body of the question, which does not match the title. When you say "shunt" in the title, people are going to assume it is the current sensing shunt resistor and not a base resistor. You can edit to clarify.

Comment: @ChecheRomo Personally, I'd like to see a lot more than just this "concept drawing of one piece of it." You want to get up to 5 A. (At least 3 A.) You have something that supposedly already does 1.5 A (1st stage that I cannot see.) And you want to monitor the load current with a high-side resistor and some ... I'm not sure what ... circuit. I'm just a hobbyist. So maybe my imagination is too limited or I can't understand what you hint at as well as I should. But I feel I need a lot more from you than what I see above before I could be of any possible help to you.

Comment: @jonk Well, I tried to isolate the section I am currently designing from all the circuit, I isolated in such a way that nothing that is not on the schematic has no direct relation with that I am trying to ask about, the first stage is LM317 Adjustable voltage regulator, you can google it, the way I intend to sense the current through the 0.1 ohm resistor is by measuring the voltage across it with a differential amplifier, but has no relation on wether a base resistor is needed for the BJT or not, I just thought isolating the problem was better.

Comment: @ChecheRomo  So, is the LM317 providing the (+) input to your 2nd stage opamp shown here? (Seems weird to me, if so.) If not, where is the LM317 output, exactly?

Comment: @jonk look at : http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slvs044x/slvs044x.pdf ; exactly at page 10, Figure 9.

Comment: @ChecheRomo That doesn't tell me how you are applying things. So why aren't you considering Fig. 23? You want more current compliance. Why not work out a way to get a current sense into that? I'm still missing something and I believe part of the reason is that you aren't writing enough.

Comment: The part missing from Fig.23 is the current sensing, this is the stage that will enable current sensing, the way of sensing current is to measure the voltage drop across the 0.1 ohm resistor with a differential amplifier as told some comments up. This voltage drop across the capacitor will not affect the voltage across the load, that should be the same as Vin. The whole reason for this circuit is keeping the load at the same voltage as Vin while sensing the current drawn by it.

Comment: @ChecheRomo Yes, Fig. 23 doesn't have current sensing. Neither does your Fig. 9. I'm still not sure how you are connecting all this up. If you want to keep me in the dark, or prefer to decide that I'm too stupid to talk to about it, that's fine with me. I still don't see the larger picture. What's wrong with adding your resistor to Fig. 23, at the appropriate point, or otherwise adding ground-return (easy) sensing to it? I'll leave it. My knowledge and ability to understand is obviously not well-fitted to your communication skills and project. That's no reflection on you. I'll take the hit.

Comment: Vout from Fig 9, goes to the positive input of the opamp of this circuit, I am sorry, I thought that was obvious. But I was lazy enough to not place it anywhere, I am sorry, as the first stage output is only a DC voltage with reference to ground that is the only thing that the second stage of this device will see. I am not skilled or something, nor was I refering tat you weren't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, a base resitor would provide some protection for the opamp. In the case of a short circuit of the output to ground (I mean the overall output, a load of 0Ω), the base of the transistor is pinned to 0.7V. With the transistor base near zero volts, the opamp output is effectively short circuited to ground too. It can dissipate a lot of power.

My approach to calculating some sort of current limit would be to figure out what maximum base current should flow under full load (\$I_B = \frac{I_C}{\beta}\$), and also how much voltage across the base resistor you can afford to "lose". Choose a resistor which easily meets both those criteria.

I suspect that 5A is too much for a single pass transistor. At 5A, with β of 50, that's 100mA of base current that your opamp needs to supply. And that amount of base current will certainly give your opamp a hard time, especially when the output is set very low. Maybe you need a darlington pair, and even parallel pass transistors.

Consider something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdQg7U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This drops the current your opamp needs to supply by a factor of 100 or so, so it doesn't need to be a beast any more.

I've used the sense resistors to also act as ballast to overcome transistor mismatch. It's just an idea, and will need work to figure out the exact values. R5 and R6 just "average" the voltages drop across the sense resistors, so you have some signal to represent current through them.

Also, you'll need to add frequency compensation if you expect any capacitive loads, because both your original circuit and this one will oscillate to hell and back without it.

Answer (score 1):

What it will do is basically waste power, since the opamp will do its best to modify it's output to make the negative terminal to the postive one. So you'll still get 10V on the load, there will still be a voltage drop on the 100mΩ resistor and a slight amount of power wasted.

So you don't need it. One thing you might need is a resistor between the opamp and the transistor because you might exceed the output current on the opamp. Or if the opamp output can source a lot of current, you might exceed Ib on the transistor, so make sure neither of those situations doesn't occur. Another problem with these circuits is they can become unstable at high frequencies, especially if there is a cable adding inductance on the load, so watch out for that.

A useful thing to do  with this circuit and a variable load is to use the shunt resistor for current measurement.

Comment: The OP actually is asking if a resistor is needed between the op-amp output and BJT base. In the body of the question anyways, which doesn't match the title.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know there will be some power loss, but i think is a fair tradeoff for being able to sense the current through the load at a precise voltage, also with a 0.1 ohm resistor the power loss wouldn't be much, at 3A dc , 0.9 watts would be wasted. How can I approach doing the calculations for the base resistor?, I think this resistor would limit the maximum current through the BJT, right?

Comment: I usually use a spice package and a 100Ω resistor to start, its really only when the transistor is saturated when things become a problem, because the opamp want's to add more and more current. Just make sure the opamp output is smaller than Ib

Comment: To measure current put the Sense resistor in the collector circuit, that way it makes it much easier to measure the voltage drop hence the current. This will allow you a wide voltage adjustment on the load without changing your sensing.